# Pattern version reflected as N/A

Tags: deepsecurity

I have pulled a CSV report through API where some of the servers reported pattern version as N/A. When I have manually checked those servers in Trend Console I can see their pattern version in updates.
Is there any to fix this reporting issue? And what is the root cause behind it?

```
Affected servers reported below information in the report,
Status: Managed (Online)
Agent Version: 11.0.0.390
Anti-Malware Status: Anti-Malware: On
Scan Pattern Version: N/A
```

Checked all details in Trend knowledge base but didn't see any information/issue reported by someone else.

Checked all details in Trend knowledge base but didn't see any information/issue reported by someone else.

Comment: This does not sound like expected behaviour. Could you please open a case with Deep Security support? https://success.trendmicro.com

Comment: I have already raised a case and they asked to raise it Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure without more details (DSM version, how you called the API, etc), but this is likely resulting from a docs issue which showed "security updates" info (including pattern versions) as available through the API and SDK, when it was not yet available.

Currently, security updates info is available through /api on 12.0 and Deep Security as a Service. As well, the latest docs and SDKs from 11.3 and earlier correctly show that security updates is not available.

P.S. I work in R&D for Deep Security